# C# Sort XML File using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this XML file that I would like to sort by year and then by month. I have tried to use linq to xml but it will not sort the file.

> Is there anything else that I will need?

XML File

```
 <Monthly>
        <Totals Month="1" Year="2019"><Total>698560</Total><Distinct>103798</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month="12" Year="2018"><Total>556091</Total><Distinct>90550</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month="11" Year="2018"><Total>638932</Total><Distinct>100398</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month="10" Year="2018"><Total>721583</Total><Distinct>106044</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month="9" Year="2018"><Total>620371</Total><Distinct>97455</Distinct></Totals>
    </Monthly>
```

Code:

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(XmlSource);

    XmlNodeList MonthlyTotals = xml.SelectNodes("//Report/Monthly");
var list = MonthlyTotals.XPathSelectElements("//Report/Monthly").OrderBy(r => r.Value);
```

//Added new logic but the code Never Completes

```
var SortedListMonthlyTotals = new XElement("Monthly", MonthlyTotals.Element("Monthly")
                .Elements()
                .OrderBy(e => (int)e.Attribute("Year"))
                   .ThenBy(e => (int)e.Attribute("Month"))
        );
```

Comment: You aren't sorting by the fields you want at all. You're sorting by `Value`, whatever it is

Comment: Actually, it's sorting using the comparator for whatever type `e` is, in reverse order.

Comment: "I have tried to use linq to xml " - the posted code is using XmlDocument _and_  Linq, but not Linq to XML.

Comment: Now you have edited in part of my answer. Don't do that. At least make a new section and explain what and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
var result = root.Elements("Totals")
                 .OrderBy(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("Year").Value))
                 .ThenBy(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("Month").Value));
```

Complete Code

```
var str = @"<Monthly>
        <Totals Month='1' Year='2019'><Total>698560</Total><Distinct>103798</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month='12' Year='2018'><Total>556091</Total><Distinct>90550</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month='11' Year='2018'><Total>638932</Total><Distinct>100398</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month='10' Year='2018'><Total>721583</Total><Distinct>106044</Distinct></Totals>
        <Totals Month='9' Year='2018'><Total>620371</Total><Distinct>97455</Distinct></Totals>
    </Monthly>";

    var root =  XElement.Parse(str);
    var result = root.Elements("Totals")
                     .OrderBy(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("Year").Value))
                     .ThenBy(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("Month").Value));
```

Output

[image]